# Tableau Percentiles with fixed ranges

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have table A.
[image]

So for example in this case. 95th percentile would be 63 <= x < 65,96th would be 65 <= x < 67 so on and so forth. Anything below 95th percentile can be categorized as 94. It's not relevant.
These values are deciding percentiles and these values will not always be the same.
(Also worth noting here, these percentile thresholds are not following a set variation/pattern)
So the ranges we decide here for 95-100 percentiles will be used to categorize actual values for each site coming from another datasource, for every 5 minute timestamp. [image: Something like this]

I am trying to achieve the expected percentile column results above in tableau desktop.